# Synonyms or Word matching

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

A company is sharing a file with me for Machine learning. They problem is that there are lots of references related to the same organisation and what I need to do is change them all to a consistant standard within the file.
The organisation is called Clarks however it is referred to various names in the files as Clarks UK, Clarks IE, Clarks LTD, Clarks Org, Clarks EMEA and a host more different alternatives. What I need to do is match these or change these all to one consistant organisation name i.e. Clarks LTD.
Which Python library would be the best to do this as part of my data transformation ETL process. Advice greatfully accepted

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what your goal is. Additionally, the size and structure of your dataset is not properly described, so it is a bit difficult to answer this question properly.

Nevertheless, if you have lots of data, I highly advise against using pandas, since it is very slow on large amounts of data (I think its matching time is linear if I remember correctly).

If your dataset structure permits, using dictionaries would definitely be the way since they have a O(1) write time and O(n) read time in the worst case. Once your dictionary is built, you can quickly and easily change whatever in your data if needs be, and then finally convert your dictionary to a list or numpy array easily.

Alternatively, you could loop through your samples and match samples which require correction with a regex expression and replace them with the required representation.